# How to use ansible to detect the specific flavor of Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, ansible

*How can I use ansible to detect the specific flavor of Linux, e.g. "Lubuntu" -- a variant of Ubuntu?*

On a Lubuntu 22.04, I tried to track `ansible_distribution` with the following playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  become: false
  tasks:
  - name: Distribution
    debug: msg="{{ ansible_distribution }}"
  - name: Distribution version
    debug: msg="{{ ansible_distribution_version}}"
  - name: Distribution major version
    debug: msg="{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}"
```

But I got `Ubuntu` as the `ansible_distribution`, which isn't specific enough (for the task I have):

```
TASK [Distribution] ************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": "Ubuntu"
}
...
```

*In general, how can one get the name of the specific Linux flavor such as Lubuntu?*

-- Additional Info --

On the Lubuntu, I have:

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

Comment: What is the content of `/etc/lsb-release` ?

Comment: @VladimirBotka Please see the update I just added.

Comment: Forgetting Ansible for a moment; how would *you* identify a Lubuntu system vs. a generic Ubuntu system?

Comment: Depending on the target system you may need to construct the information from values gathered on the Remote Node like in [Getting full name of the OS using Ansible facts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71034832/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard for recognizing [Ubuntu flavors](https://ubuntu.com/desktop/flavours). You can search for the configuration. See [Is it possible to know which recognized flavor I am running using terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452182/is-it-possible-to-know-which-recognized-flavor-i-am-running-using-terminal). For example,

```bash
shell> cat /var/log/installer/media-info 
Xubuntu 20.04 LTS "Focal Fossa" - Release amd64 (20200423)
```

Ansible doesn't [gather facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/gather_facts_module.html#ansible-builtin-gather-facts-module-gathers-facts-about-remote-hosts) about Ubuntu flavors. You'll have to find out on your own. For example,

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    my_flavor: "{{ media_info.stdout.split()|first }}"

  tasks:

    - command: cat /var/log/installer/media-info
      register: media_info
    - debug:
        var: my_flavor
```

gives

```yaml
  my_flavor: Xubuntu
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ansible_distribution_release`

You can easily see available facts on your host by running:

```
ansible all -m setup -a "filter=ansible_distribution*"

"ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_distribution": "Ubuntu",
        "ansible_distribution_file_parsed": true,
        "ansible_distribution_file_path": "/etc/os-release",
        "ansible_distribution_file_variety": "Debian",
        "ansible_distribution_major_version": "22",
        "ansible_distribution_release": "jammy",
        "ansible_distribution_version": "22.04",
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"
    },
```

Comment: This shows the release name, not the flavour.